Integrate openapi-generate with Conan 2 and CMake with proper caching
I need to integrate multiple OpenApi definitions that I generate with the openapi-generator into my Conan 2 and CMake based project.
I currently have a somewhat working version, but there are two issues:

The OpenAPI stubs get rebuild unconditionally during every conan build step, even if the OpenAPI YML files have not changed. I think there must be a better solution that reuses the generated files from the cache, if the inputs did not change.
I am integrating the openapi stubs via add_subdirectory into the main cmake projects, but I think the generated stubs are intended to be built separately and resolved via a find_package directive in the main project.

I would like to understand if I should call the openapi-generator from Conan or from CMake and how I can achive a more efficient integration.
Currently I am doing roughly the following:

Add a tool dependency in conan: tool_requires = "openapi-generator/7.8.0"
Call self.run(f"openapi-generator generate -i ... -o ... -g cpprest-sdk <other options>") from the build method before I run cmake.build(). I need to do this at build time, since I was not able to move the dependencies to the generate method. At generation time the tool_requires dependencies are not fully resolved and then self.run will not find the openapi-generator in the path. For this reason, I had to add a skipBuild option to the build method, so that users can run conan build -o skipBuild=True --output-folder ./build after conan install and afterwards continue to run the cmake configure and build steps from their IDE.

Should I move the generation steps into CMake or is it correct to handle this from Conan? Is there a better way to generate the implementation so that Conan (or CMake) can reuse previously generated files?
Update:
The openapi-generator actually generates folders that are considered self-contained CMake projects. This means they have their own CMakeLists.txt. After building and installing the module a xxxConfig.CMake file is generated that can be used to resolve the stubs (via find_package) from the main CMake project that is consuming the stubs.
This implies that the generated folder needs to exist at configure time so CMake can resolve it. Therefore using CMake directives like add_custom_command to invoke the openapi-generator and generate the stubs on the fly as part of building the main CMake project is not a feasible option and using Conan is therefore the correct approach. However, the correct details on how to achieve the integration is still a bit unclear to me.
Lets unpack the issues a bit further.
Efficient Caching and regeneration
This is only relevant at development time, since in a CI/CD pipeline that builds the conan package we are always going through a full conan create flow that installs, build and packages the project and we do not cache anything. But during development, we want to be able to run conan install once and then go into a development loop where we modify the sources and continuously rebuild with cmake them without calling conan install again. That creates and issue since each time the openapi stubs are changed the users need to go back to conan and run the conan build step again. I was originally thinking that I can resolve that by using a add_custom_target and add_custom_command directive into cmake, so that CMake uses its built-in dependency graph to determine if the api definitions have changed and then rebuilds the stubs on-demand, but as I explained above, this is not possible (at least not with the default bundled CMakeLists.txt from the openapi-generator).
Integration via Conan
My current solution, using add_subdirectory to reference the generated stubs and build them as part of the main project also has some drawbacks. For example it produces .a files from the stubs that end up in the install prefix when we package the project. It looks like a better approach would be to build the openapi stubs as independent projects, which we configure, build and install first before we build the main project and resole them via CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. However, I am not sure how I can use a single conanfile.py to build multiple independent CMake projects such as by defining multiple CMakeToolchain and CMake instances, is that possible? Can I control things like the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX or the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH via my conanfile?

It sounds you should be moving the generation call to the generate() method that executes once at conan install, then you should be able to just call your cmake ... as usual, depending what "developer flow" you want compared with "conan flow", but that really depends on many factors. You can post these questions in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues to discuss directly with the maintainers.

Thanks for the reply, as a first step I moved the generate function to the install method, but I have also seen examples where the openapi-generator would be called from a custom CMake command. Is it better to keep the generation in conan or would it be more helpful to move it to CMake? With the current approach I would need to rerun conan if I make a change to the api definitions. If I moved it into CMake then CMake could rerun the generators anytime the specification changes, no?

It really depends on the developer flow. I typically much prefer scripting in Python than in CMake, not only the syntax is way better, and things that takes 10 lines in CMake can be done in 1 in Python. And if the api definition changes, calling conan install is no more effort than calling cmake. It is true that cmake might be called automatically from the build, but in my experience when the build is complicated it might be necessary to clean and fully regenerate, so in that sense it wouldn't be much better. It also depends on how often the api definition changes.
